# ASP.NET User Control Property Value Options In Designer Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, user-controls

I am using Visual Studio 2008 | .NET 3.5 | C#.  I have created an user control that has the following property: DisplayMode.  DisplayMode is meant to either display a series of text boxes or a single text box.

```
[Browsable(true),
Category("Appearance"),
DefaultValue(DISPLAY_MODE_FIELDS),
Description("Indicates whether to display the phone number as a single text box or separate fields.")]
public string DisplayMode
{
      get { return mDisplayMode; }
      set { mDisplayMode = value; }
    }
```

Therefore, I want the options of the property to either be 'Fields' or 'Single'.  I specified above I want to make this browsable in the designer, but how do I set those two values as options rather than knowing to specify 'Fields', 'Single', etc. in the future?  Is there another attribute that I can decorate the property with to list these options out or do I need to create an enum (which works)?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need any other info!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The enum is the way to go. It will provide IntelliSense for the values in the Visual Studio HTML editor, and it will be more type-safe and easier to use in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Sounds good.  Didn't know if .NET provided another attribute for this.

Answer (score 11):

Just create an Enum

In your user control -

```
    public enum OrientationOption
    { 
        Horizontal,
        Vertical
    }

    public OrientationOption Orientation { get; set; }
```

That's it ! this is how it will look like in your VS autocomplete
[image: Auto complete options in code view]

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `enum` for the `DisplayMode` attribute of your user control